# How to sort posts with meta_key using custom mysql query in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having a situation in which i have to sort the posts by their state name alphabetically (A-Z). I know we can do this by meta_query but in my case i have to do it using custom mysql query.

I tried :-

```
$quotes = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_akph_posts LEFT JOIN wp_akph_postmeta ON wp_akph_posts.ID=wp_akph_postmeta.post_id where wp_akph_posts.post_type='quote' Order by wp_akph_postmeta.meta_value ASC");
```

and i got the results as Null first (meta_key) because it is left join.

I want the anywhere, TX be on top not NULL or any number. Just the string.

Any Suggetions ?

Comment: You can standart Wordpress query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394593/wordpress-multiple-meta-key-in-pre-get-posts/26494526#26494526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cause `ORDER BY` to place `NULL` last by using a `-` before the column name in the statement. IF you have to use SQL instead of `WP_Query` I still suggest using the `$wpdb->prefix` and other built in table name values in case you use this on a site with a different prefix.

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} p 
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id 
    WHERE p.post_type='quote' 
    ORDER BY -pm.meta_value ASC
SQL;
$quotes = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

This feature of MySQL is not well documented but you can find info [here](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-order_by) as well as in the comments of the documentation.