# Wordpress custom post type table filter

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation, and I need to filter a table that's been populated with data from a custom post type.

```
register_post_type('client', $args);
```

there is a column which carries the 'type' of 'client', and i'd like to filter the results in the table using this value.

values are: active, pending, gone-away, closed

Which function(s) do I need, in order to create a dropdown box, which will be populated by the 'client' types, so that i can filter the visible results in the table ?

UPDATE: This is for the ADMIN part of the site. To filter the Tables generated there.

Comment: Is `type` a taxonomy?

Comment: Did you add custom field for this? First, add custom meta field to your custom post type.

Comment: 'type' is taken from post meta @NabilKadimi

Comment: custom meta has been added and is populated already :) @FatihSARI

Comment: @Deano Then use `wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy=type' );`, see answer below.

Comment: Please look it for Filter your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26494526/2311759

Comment: Sorry I flagged this question but should not have. My reason is not correct.